# Shopify Checkout script get cart attribute

Tags: shopify

I'm using shopify plus store. 
I want to access cart attributes in checkout script editor. 
Is there any way to get cart attributes in checkout script editor?

```
{
token: "18da3b31a1b1d045500ad49e17836d5a",
note: "",
attributes: {
simply_test: "1"
},
original_total_price: 2900,
total_price: 2900,
total_discount: 0,
total_weight: 0,
item_count: 1,
items: [..],
requires_shipping: true,
currency: "USD"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible

```
<script>

// Get cart values
$.getJSON( "/cart.js")
    .done(function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });


// Update cart values
$.post('/cart/update.js', {
    attributes: {
        'Gift wrap': 'maybe',
        'Name': 'Johnny Deep',
    }
});


</script>
```

Comment: I was talking about checkout script editor, not JS code.
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/script-editor

Comment: You can use JS to access the cart in the checkout file. I am not sure if you can have access to the cart current products using liquid on that file

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the cart attributes anywhere on Shopify:

```
await fetch('/cart.js', {
  method: 'GET'
})
```

Comment: I don't need attr on the Front side I'm talking about the Shopify Checkout script
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor

Answer (score 0):

I would adjust your shop so that you transfer the info you store in cart attributes as line item properties. Those do transfer to checkout scripts. Does not look good for cart note or attributes.

Comment: That's the point. I want attribute, if i use line item then i have to apply things on all products.

Comment: You will have to invent your own system to get cart attributes into checkout, and as I said, the only R/W properties that seem flexible and make it to checkout scripts are the line item properties.

Comment: FWIW, this is still the case. I am working around same problem by adding them at line item level.